# CakePHP and Android Auth Idea. Suggestions Please

Tags: cakephp, android-studio

Well I have this situation where I should authenticate user with CakePHP 2.x site which is using blowfish to save password and I am using GCM for push notifications.

I am thinking it this way. First I will generate a registration ID for the device and then use the web view to open a custom login page designed for android in Server. There if the user successfully authenticates, his device id, registration id and the site recognized username are stored in a table. All requests with saved device id and registration id are used to authenticate a user and perform his actions. There would be mechanisms to control the problems with registration id where it gets deactivated or re issued.

Does this have any security issues or design flaws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a token based stateless auth system I think.

Use http://oauth.net/2/ for that. This is exactly what it was made for.

And I don't think your idea is secure: It sounds like the device id and the registration id will be the always the same (per device) and stored on the device - not a good idea. However it works, no need to re-invent the wheel.

And use HTTPS for that, OAuth2 requires it because unlike OAuth1 it doesn't deal with the cryptographic part any more but passes this task on to HTTPS.